# Erro na declaração da class no react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estou criando uma aplicação react native com o seguinte fluxo:
Meu `App.js` importa os components header, body e footer. O `body.js` faz a importação de uma classe de eventos chamada de `Play`.

Porém, na declaração `var evento = Play();` da class Play está gerando o erro:

Sabem o que pode estar acontecendo?

> (0, _play.defalt) is not a function. (In '(0, play.defalt)()','(0,
>   _play.defalt)' is undefined)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**body.js**

```
var evento = Play();

export default class Body extends Component {
    render() {
        const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('');
        return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Type what you hear</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
            title="Play"
            onPress={evento.onPressButtonPlay.bind(this)}>
            <Image
                source={require('../resources/img/play.jpg')}
                style={styles.play}
            />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TextInput
            style={styles.textarea}
            onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
            value={value}
            />
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**play.js**

```
    export class Play {
        constructor() {
            this.song = null;
        }

        onPressButtonPlay() {
            this.song = new Sound('my_sound.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, error => {
            if (error)
                ToastAndroid.show(
                'Error when init SoundPlayer :(((' + error.message,
                ToastAndroid.SHORT,
                );
            else {
                this.song.play(success => {
                if (!success)
                    ToastAndroid.show(
                    'Error when play SoundPlayer :(((',
                    ToastAndroid.SHORT,
                    );
                });
            }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Não deveria ser

```js
var evento = new Play();
```